# In terms of matrices: $\forall v\in V,\phi(\phi(v))=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$\phi: V\to V$( a linear operator here)

How to interpret $\forall v\in V,\phi(\phi(v))=0$ in terms of matrices? Can I have some hint?

---

I suppose $\phi(V)= \begin{bmatrix} \phi(v_1)\\\phi(v_2)\\\dots\\\phi(v_n)\end{bmatrix}$ for $V=\dim n$

Comment: Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider $\phi(x,y)=(y,0)$.What is the matrix representing $\phi$?

Comment: @Moya $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Yes! Now, do you see that $\phi(\phi(x,y))=0$?

Comment: @Moya Oh that does work indeed, thanks. I am trying to find all such linear operators, but I wasn't sure how to think of it and this helps. So I am looking at some matrix representationm, $M$, for $\phi$ and taking $MMV=0$?

Comment: Yes, you take the matrix representation of $\phi$ in some fixed basis and you want that $M^2=0$, since this is the only operator with this property. These are called nilpotent matrices if you're curious (actually, nilpotent refers to a matrix $M$ such that $M^n=0$ for some $n$. This is the special case $n=2$).

Comment: @Moya Would it be called $2-\operatorname{Nilpotent}$ then, or in some way mention that the $n=2$? Thanks for that, grad to know

Comment: It's called the degree.

Comment: @Moya This helped an immense amount, the wiki article on Nilpotent matrices is insanely relevant to my confusion. Thank you so much

Comment: Here is a hint: try to think in terms of the diagonals...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\phi(\phi(v))=0$ is equivalent to saying that this $A^2=0$. What does this mean? This means that $A$ has a nilpotency index of $2$. So what we want is to find all nilpotent index $2$ matrices of size $n\times n$. What matrices satisfy this?

All matrices are similar to a Jordan form and hence there is some $J$ Jordan form satisfying  $A=P^{-1} J A$. This $J^2=0$ also, and since all nilpotent matrices have eigenvalues of $0$, we form some combination of Jordan blocks of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&\\0&0&1\\&&\ddots&\ddots\\0&\dots&&0&1\\0&\dots&&&0\end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}$$

Now another fact we know is the following:

$$J^2=\begin{bmatrix}{J_1}^2\\&{J_2}^2\\&&\ddots\\&&&&{J_n}^2\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $J_i$ are the jordan blocks making up this Jordan form. What this means is, each of $J_i$ must have a nilpotency index of $2$.

What size Jordan blocks have a nilpotency index of $2$?

$\begin{bmatrix}0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ are the only two such sizes. Why? The three by three case and above will always have a nilpotency index greater than $2$.

This means that all such matrices are equivalent to some permutation of Jordan blocks of size $1$ and $2$ across the diagonal.